# How to use JAX-WS client in Websphere 7

Tags: jax-ws

I use JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in jdk6 (wsimport tool) to generate client stubs and successfully called the new API using simple POJO.  But when I deploy on Websphere7 I get :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException
```

Inserting axis2-jaxws jar causes `Service` class to be taken from `apache.axis2.Service` instead of `javax.xml.ws.Service`.

How do I resolve this issue Nullpointerissue ?

FYI: Right now the EAR policy is 'parent-last'. If I set module also to 'parent-last' other services also don't work. Also  I cannot access the computer where the server is deployed. I only see server console.
Thanks.

Comment: There's just not enough information in your post. @WebServiceRef annotation should be enough to inject managed client, if the referenced wsdl is accessible.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen  
How I call the client:
HelloWorldImplService helloService = new HelloWorldImplService();   HelloWorld hello = helloService.getHelloWorldImplPort();  
hello.myClientMethod(params);  
This works.When I deploy in WAS7 I got issues as JAX-WS support was in WAS7 too.So I added jax-ws api , saaj-api ,jaxb-api in pom and modified the scope to provided. Set the class loading to parent first.It worked now but I don't get the required response.I get: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addHeader WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
Any more jars needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue myself.
The 'Response already committed' issue was some wrong piece of code. With the above dependencies scope set to 'provide' the error for this original post should be resolved in Websphere 7.
Thanks all anyway.